# Exporting an imported library

Tags: cmake

I have projectA, into which I'm importing a library with:

```
add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /path/to/foo.a)
```

I then use `foo` in several places within the project, and it all works fine.

A couple of directory levels down I want to export a library built within this project for use in yet another project with a completely disconnected CMake config. I've got:

```
...
target_link_libraries(thislib foo)
export(TARGETS thislib FILE /path/to/thislib.cmake)
```

The importing projectB also needs foo though (because the imported library needs it), and complains that it `cannot find -lfoo`. I tried adding it to the `export` command, but then I get:

```
CMake Error at thislib/CMakeLists.txt:37 (export):
  export given target "foo" which is not built by this project.
```

I just want to export the same configuration I use locally to the other (importing) project. I don't want to have to tell projectB about `foo` explicitly. Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

I also can't find an ideal way to do this. But here is the workaround I'm using for now. It's extra work, and not DRY, but I think it achieves the right thing.

Imagine lib `B` depends on third party lib `A`. `A` either has a find module defined, or we can implement a custom find module for it. Both are doable. Assume we've already written `FindA.cmake` and stored in in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake`. Also, let's assume that when you run cmake to generate `B`'s build system, you provide `A_ROOT` to help cmake locate `A`.

Then in B's top-level `CMakeLists.txt` we need:

```
# Use FindA.cmake, defined in the cmake/ directory.
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(A REQUIRED)

# ... (define the B target here)...

# Copy the config file to the build dir
configure_file(cmake/BConfig.cmake cmake/BConfig.cmake @ONLY)

# Copy A's find module (skip this step if FindA is not custom).
configure_file(cmake/FindA.cmake cmake/FindA.cmake COPYONLY)

# Create the target export.
export(EXPORT BTargets
    FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/BTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE B::
    )

# Register B so cmake can find B's config file.
export(PACKAGE B)
```

Now in `cmake/BConfig.cmake`:

```
# Get the exported find module onto the module path.
# This step is unnecessary if the find module is part of cmake.
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")

# Store the root so that find_package will work.
# You may have to store other variables here, too, but
# the principle is just more of the same.
set(A_ROOT @A_ROOT@) # **Could optionally cache this.
find_package(A MODULE REQUIRED)

# The usual one-liner for a config file.
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/BTargets.cmake")
```

Just to drive the solution home, let's look at a second example, `Rocket` this time using `Boost`, which already has a find module defined.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
option(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem program_options)

add_library(Rocket rocket.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Rocket
    PUBLIC Boost::filesystem
    PRIVATE Boost::program_options
    )

configure_file(cmake/BConfig.cmake cmake/BConfig.cmake @ONLY)

export(EXPORT RocketTargets 
    FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/RocketTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE Rocket::
    )
export(PACKAGE Rocket)
```

Then `cmake/RocketConfig.cmake` would have:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT @BOOST_ROOT@ CACHE PATH "In case boost was relocated.")
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED @Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED@)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC LIBS @Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS@)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem program_options)

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/RocketTargets.cmake")
```

So yeah. It seems like too much typing. It seems like cmake should be able to generate all of that code from an `export` statement in `CMakeLists.txt`. But this strategy seems to achieve the goal.

Also, I haven't tested yet, but I suspect that, if your transitive dependency uses a `CONFIG` instead of a `MODULE` for `find_package`, it should be very easy just to add to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in your config file as well.

Edit (2021): Tsyvarev has pointed out the `find_dependency()` macro, which can simplify the above approach somewhat. Consider using that instead of `find_package()`.

Comment: Yes, adding search for `A` package inside the script `BConfig.cmake` is a correct approach. But instead of `find_package`, it is better to implement that search via [find_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) macro. That macro automatically "derives" REQUIRED option from the call `find_package(B)`, and in case of failure to find `A` it prints the name of `B` package too. Before using `find_dependency` macro one should include CMake script which defines it: `include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know about that macro at the time, but the documentation makes it very clear. That's the problem with CMake - it's well documented in the details, but so complicated it can be hard to find out what features exist and how best to use them.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find an actual solution for the problem as stated, but am posting my own workaround for future reference.

I realized that the `foo` dependency *was* being emitted in the export; it just didn't have a path with it. And since I still haven't figured out how to get cmake to export the path along with it, I reverted my `export` command to that shown in the question above (without `foo`).

Then I went back to the original place where `foo` was being imported and removed the `add_library` and `set_property`, replacing them with this:

```
set(foo /path/to/foo.a)
```

Then changed the `target_link_libraries` to:

```
target_link_libraries(thislib ${foo})
```

In other words, rather than making it a real "imported library", it's just a raw library path. This does get correctly written into the export file and allows projectB to link.

Comment: One problem with that is that it doesn't allow you to set target properties such as INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES

Comment: Another problem is that your path will be copied in export scripts, which makes them most probably useless on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Export `foo` from where it is built (to, say, `foolibs.cmake`)
2. Instead of using `/path/to/thislib.cmake` directly (the export file generated by `export(TARGETS thislib...` create another one, `thislib-and-deps.cmake` which includes both:

   ```
   include(<...>/foolibs.cmake)
   include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/thislib.cmake)
   ```

Comment: Does an easy solution exist to implement this in a reusable manner without implementing lots of CMake code per project? This doesn't seem to be the *CMake-way-to-go*. Currently I repeat the `find_package(<name> CONFIG)` call for each transitive dependency, which also sucks, since it breaks the concept of transitive dependencies.